# How to store a space in a char array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a Caesar Cypher program but I can't figure out how to store a space in my char array. Here is my encrypt method

```
public static String encrypt(String msg, int shift)  {
    char[] list = msg.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        // Shift letter
        char letter = list[i];
        letter = (char) (letter + shift);
        if (letter > 'z') {
            letter = (char) (letter - 26);
        }
        else if (letter < 'a') {
            letter = (char) (letter + 26);
        }
        else if (letter == ' ') {
            letter = '\0';
        }
        list[i] = letter;
    }
    // Return final string.
    return new String(list);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Literally, the answer to your question is:

```
    list[i] = ' ';
```

However, your code as written looks rather broken.  Hint: think carefully about:

- what happens to characters that aren't letters in the range `a` to `z` (lower case!), and
- what happens to `letter` *before* this test - `if (letter == ' ') { ...`.

Answer (score 1):

A space is a character similar to any other letter:

```
char space[] = {' '};
```

or

```
myCharArray[i] = ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

ascii codes for storing spaces and then compare it with the characters.This link might help you

http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/space-ascii-code-32.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic error- you only compare the letter to the space character *after* you apply the shift. You should check whether the character is a space, and then only shift it if it is one of the characters you want to shift (probably just letters and numbers).

**After** fixing that, you *could* store it the same way you check it:

```
if ( letter == ' '){
    letter = ' ';
} else {
    //logic for shifting
}
```

Though really this would be unnecessary. It would be more appropriate to have

```
if ( letter != ' '){
        //logic for shifting
}
```

And **really really**, it is more appropriate to have something like:

```
if(shouldShift(letter)){
    //logic for shifting
}
```

Where `shouldShift` is something like:

```
public boolean shouldShift(char letter){
    return Character.isLetter(letter) || Character.isDigit(letter);
}
```